# Which order i should follow to upgrade in Python, DJango and DJango-cms?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.7, django-cms

I have to upgrade my python project, Which currently running on Python **2.7**/Django **1.10.8** and Django-cms **3.4.5**.

To version,
Python **3.7**
Django **2.2**
Django-cms **3.6**

May I know, From where I should start and is there any upgrade tools like Pylint to do this?

Comment: Server-wise, if you are using a Python-based deployment tool like Ansible or Saltstack, or if you are running a server distribution (Ubuntu LTS 18.04 is at 3.6) you want to include that in your planning too.  Also, while prepping your code in 2.7 you can still run **black** and it tends to flag Python 3 *syntax* issues.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu(16.04) environment. Thanks, I'll try.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the safest upgrade route as it keeps you in support windows at each step.

- First, do the jump from python2.7 to python3.5 (at first you are only going to be able to get to version python 3.5 because of version support). This is also most likely to be the hardest step because a number of other packages and dependencies will need to be updated from python2.7->3.

  - When I have tackled this in the past I have used [python-modernize](https://python-modernize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to help accomplish the code migration. But, going through the packages is going to be a slow process (make sure you have some form of testing in place).
- Next upgrade django to 1.11.
- Then upgrade django-cms to 3.6 (latest version)
- Now upgrade django to version 2.2 (latest version, LTS)
- Now upgrade python to 3.7 (latest version)

Doing it in this order will keep you in support windows throughout the upgrade process.

An alternative option as a result of conversations in the comments is to do: Courtesy of [@dirkgroten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1252711/) and [@alasdair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113962/). This has the added advantage of skipping the python3.5 upgrade.

- Upgrade django to the latest 1.11.X (currently 1.11.22). You should always use the latest minor Django version so that you are not missing out on security fixes, and Python 3.7 support wasn't added until 1.11.17.
- Upgrade django-cms to 3.6 (latest version)
- Upgrade Python to 3.7 (latest version)
- Upgrade django to latest 2.2.X (LTS)

Comment: why django 1.11 as in-between step?

Comment: As django cms version 3.4.5 supports up to django 1.11. If you go higher than django 1.11 too soon you fall out of django cms support windows. And CMS 3.6 does not support django versions less than 1.10.

Comment: Note that django 1.11 still supports Python 2.7, so it should also possible to first upgrade to django 1.11, then to Python3.5, etc... Not that it should make a huge difference though ;-)

Comment: @dirkgroten ignoring Python/Django-CMS upgrades, it's a good idea to upgrade Django 1.10 -> Django 1.11 LTS -> Django 2.2 LTS anyway. Once your (py3) code runs on Django 1.11 without any deprecation warnings, it should run on Django 2.X. If you jump straight from Django 1.10 to 2.2, then [these deprecations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/deprecation/#deprecation-removed-in-2-1) may catch you out.

Comment: Based on the comments above and assuming that at each step you want to have a functional app (all tests passing), I would now think that the following order makes it a bit easier: django 1.11 > django-cms 3.6 > python 3.7 > django 2.2. Although going from python 3.5 to 3.7 isn't much of an issue in terms of your code, it's nice if you can avoid it, since it requires to setup a new virtualenv.

Comment: @Matt Seymour What about the database migration from the lower version to latest(2.2) django (with data).

Comment: @ShankarThiyagaraajan that will be part of the specific django-cms and django upgrades. We are not only talking about "code" above.